# how to detect if a task has execute in the last 2 minutes in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, timer, task

I have a project that has Json in it - when a user come back to the home page because of view didLoad method the app will start getting son again and I want this But I want the app detect that if the user has came back to the home page in the last 2 minutes the app doesn't get the json - simply I want to run a task when user go to a view controller but if user has came back to the view controller in the last 2 minutes the app doesn't execute task and for example if the user open the app and go to the another page after 3 minutes when he came back to the home page the task start - as you see here I can use timer but the timer will run the task every minutes I want to limit this as I said

```
weak var timer: Timer?

func startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
    // do something here
    }
}

func stopTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
}

// if appropriate, make sure to stop your timer in `deinit`

deinit {
    stopTimer()
}
```

Comment: Save the last json request execution time in one of the keys in your NSUserdefaults. Everytime your user come to home page and you want to fire json request, just compare it with last execution time. If its more than 2 mins fire it otherwise don't.

Comment: so you mean I get the system time(minute) and when the task wants to start  I write for example if currentminute - task minute > 0 { run the task ?

Comment: Not just minute comparison. Do entire date comparison to avoid other handlings of minutes. you can convert both your dates in timeinmilliseconds and just have that value greater then  180*1000 milliseconds. I have added that as an answer as well.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the last json request execution time in one of the keys in your NSUserdefaults.

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()    

// save to user defaults
userDefaults.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "LastExecutionDate")
```

Everytime your user come to home page and you want to fire json request, just compare it with last execution time. If its more than 2 mins fire it otherwise don't.

```
// retrieve from user defaults
let lastExecutionDate = userDefaults.objectForKey("LimitReachedOnDate") as? NSDate
```

Then your currentDate - lastExecutionDate > 180 seconds. This is just a algo and not the exact code for date comparison but i guess you will get it. this

Answer (score 2):

You would need to save the Date(time) object when the task gets completed in the completion handler and then next time when you are about to start the task you would need to check the time elapsed.

1. Set a Date in UserDefaults in the completion handler of your task.
2. Before proceeding to start task check whether this Date exists and if exists, then the elapsed time is greater than 120 seconds(2 minutes) or not.

> ```
>  func startTaskIfPossible() {
>         let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "taskCompletionDate") as? Date
>         guard let prevCompletionDate = date else {
>             startTask()
>             return
>         }
>
>         guard Date().timeIntervalSince(prevCompletionDate) > 120 else {
>             return
>         }
>
>         startTask()
>     }
>
>     func startTask() {
>         //Set Date in userdefaults in completion handler of task
>         // UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Date(), forKey: "taskCompletionDate")
>     }
> ```